# C++ Why can't the string size funtion be called within constexpr function

Tags: c++, string, c++11, size, constexpr

```
   constexpr bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2)
   {
        return s1.size() < s2.size();
   }
```

When compiled it says: "error call to non-constexpr function"

Comment: `string` can use dynamic memory allocation, which makes it rather radically non-`constexpr`.

Comment: Without understanding the rest of the system this function seems pointless. Why the desire to use isShorter(s1, s2) which would require the user to know which way around these arguments need to be when s1.size() < s2.size() is much more explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a non-`constexpr` function from inside a `constexpr` one. And, as you can see from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), `std::string::size()` is not `constexpr`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::string::size()` is not `constexpr`

With literal c-string you may do:

```
template <std::size_t N1, std::size_t N2>
constexpr bool isShorter(const char (&)[N1], const char (&)[N2])
{
    return N1 < Ns;
}
```